# Instagram empty string for every bio in user object

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've tried, both via an API library in Python and the API console that Instagram and apigee.com provide.

I use the request: `GET /tags/tag-name/media/recent`.
I tried `ferrari` tag.

All results populate perfectly, except the `bio` field of the user for each media result from the tag request.

Here are a couple of result snippets:

```
"full_name": "AвтоСпаСтудия",
"bio": "",
"id": "435889630"
...

"full_name": "jacky_mitchell",
"bio": "",
"id": "1527609678"
```

They all have blank `bio` fields. The website fields are also blank for the record.

Someone else had the [same issue in the old Instagram group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/instagram-api-developers/m0RUEZmhmKQ/qNKuA1VcWNgJ).

I might have to ditch this half-working API and sniff the TCP/IP traffic and do some raw requests.

Comment: So weird, do you have the API permissions to get the bio?

Comment: Yes, I think something strange has to be going on there.

Comment: You need individual permissions to get the BIO for `GET /tags/tag-name/media/recent`?

Comment: @User What is the query you are trying? What endpoint? I've just tried in apigee.com for `GET /users/search` for `"AвтоСпаСтудия"` and I get the bio for it. Pretty sure it's an API problem. Do you have a client_id to make the request? Try this in your browser changing the request with your client_id https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=A%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F&client_id=<enter_your_client_id_here>

Comment: @User also you could try this: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

Comment: I'm querying for the recent tags. The labels are there it's just empty. I am using that library

Comment: The query I'm using is in an earlier comment.

Comment: could you provide some user name examples with empty bio?

Comment: `GET /tags/tag-name/media/recent` is the request. It's not a username being searched, but a tag.

Comment: I just did some API tests (using the API console) and got the same results. I even requested a tag I recently used, found my photo in the response, and the `bio` property was empty. Seems like an API issue to me.

Comment: Yea I agree this seems like an API issue, as a workaround can you just make the getUser call for each user you find and get the bio that way??

Comment: @JimMoody scaling that is going to really slow down everything with all the request limits they have in place

Comment: This is aexpected, as per the examples in the [API Docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/)

Comment: @marianosimone if you have a full answer, can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoints to get the `bio` and `website` fields are `/users/<user-id>` and `/users/self`.

There was a bug where some endpoints containing the `user` node would have empty `bio` and `website` fields. Those endpoints don't return those fields anymore. The sample responses in the docs have also been updated to reflect the change.

Source: http://developers.instagram.com/post/112826291271/api-bug-fixes

Comment: You're fast Alberto :)

Comment: So their solution to the problem is to just remove the fields entirely? How lazy.

Answer (score 0):

As per the examples in [Instagram API's Docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/), this is expected:

```
"user": {
    "username": "emohatch",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1242695_75sq_1293915800.jpg",
    "id": "1242695",
    "full_name": "Dave"
}
```

The only workaround might be actually getting the full info for each user (that you actually need the bio for), and try to cache results in order to avoid going over their rate limits.

Comment: Strange, because the support agent said it was a bug

Comment: If they consider it a bug, that's great... There's a chance it will be fixed. It would be nice to report the inconsistency with the docs, in that case.