# How do I scrape an Instagram bio with BeautifulSoup and Requests?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the bio of an instagram profile. 
The bio is in a div tag with `class= -vDIg`. The div tag is in a section tag. All the bio contents are in the span tag which is inside the div tag.

Here is the html: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiIRm.jpg

This is what I have tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


instaSite= input("Enter instagram profile url: ")
if not instaSite=='':
    instaRequest=requests.get(url=instaSite).text

    instaSoup = BeautifulSoup(instaRequest, 'html.parser')

    section = instaSoup.find('section')

    instaText= section.find('div', class_='-vDIg').span.text

    print(instaText)
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is meant for **specific technical issues**.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be great if you could post the HTML or dummy HTML that represents what you are reading from. It makes it easier for the community to create working solutions and help you out even more.

So if your goal is to scrape basic information from an Instagram profile, perhaps try their public facing API.This doesn't seem to include the bio, but may make your life easier for getting other information.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user

Seems like they definitely don't have the bio available
[Instagram empty string for every bio in user object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662588/instagram-empty-string-for-every-bio-in-user-object)

But with your approach, consider this: is it always true that the class '-vDIg' is the bio? Is the section tag the only section tag? In HTML, a class may be present across many tags (and there can be many tags) and should be expected to not be unique. Try another profile and find out if this is true or not.

With all the info, here is the approach I would recommend trying. Grabbing the section is good, but you've assumed that '-vDIg' is unique to that span. So lets traverse the HTML tree to the direct path.

html -> body -> div(id=react-root) -> section -> main -> div -> div -> span

So first, I translated your image to text, so this is what I'm testing with.

```
<html lang="en" class="j5 logged-in client-root js-focus-visible sDNSV">
<head></head>
<body class style>
    <div id="react-root">
        <form></form>
        <section class="_9eogI E3X2T">
            <div></div>
            <main class="SCxLW o064aR" role="main">
                <div class="v9t]q VfzDr">
                    <header class=" HVbuG">..</header>
                    <div class="-vDIg”>
                        <h1 class="rhpdm">Justin Bieber</h1>
                        <br>
                        <span>
                            “Yummy out now "
                            <br>
                            <a class="notranslate" href="/drewhouse/">@drewhouse</a>
                        </span>
                        <a class="yLUwa" href="..."></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tested this with the above HTML, and it seems to work. I imported typing so that my function has type hints with it. Th recurse_find simply iterates through the list of strings and reassigns the soup then returns it. Thus the walk that I mentioned above holds true when you get the finalSoup.text.

```
from typing import List

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def recurse_find(soup: BeautifulSoup, xs: List[str]) -> BeautifulSoup:
    for x in xs:
        soup = soup.find(x)
    return soup 

# this is a recursive version of the above function
# but I suggest using the above function
# because Python does not optimize tail recursion
def recursive_find(soup: BeautifulSoup, xs: List[str]) -> BeautifulSoup:
    if(len(xs)) <= 0:
        return soup;
    else:
        head, *tail = xs
        return recursive_find(soup.find(head), tail)

instaSite= input("Enter instagram profile url: ")
if not instaSite=='':
    instaRequest=requests.get(url=instaSite).text

    instaSoup = BeautifulSoup(instaRequest, 'html.parser')

    section = soup.find(id="react-root")
    finalSoup = recurse_find(soup, ["section", "main", "div", "div", "span"])

    instaText = finalSoup.text
    # also consider the following
    # instaText = str.strip(finalSoup.text)
    print(instaText)
```

Comment: THANK YOU, I had a hard time understanding BeautifulSoup but this explains it clearly. I never thought about using a recursive function to iterate through the html tree. I was using tons of variable to store one by one to do it. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I'm glad it helped out! But my function is not recursive at all. Since the function does not call itself, it is not recursive by definition. I typically avoid recursion in python because python does not optimize tail recursion (long story short, a stack overflow can happen if you recurse a function too many times). I updated my answer to use a tail recursive function, but I don't suggest using it.

Comment: Oh and if this answers your question, could you please vote on my answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try attaching `?__a=1` to the URL address of the profile page, which will give you JSON output that is easy to parse.

Example page - https://www.instagram.com/keanu_reeevesss/?__a=1

Example output

```
{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_33898987401","show_suggested_profiles":false,"show_follow_dialog":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"\ud83d\udc76 2nd September 1964 \ud83d\udc76\n\u2022\n\u26a0\ufe0fI\u2019M NOT KEANU REEVES \u26a0\ufe0f\n\u2022\n\u274c FAKE KEANU ACCOUNTS WILL BE BLOCKED \u274c","blocked_by_viewer":false,"restricted_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":null,"external_url_linkshimmed":null,"edge_followed_by":{"count":128170},"fbid":"17841433942037373","followed_by_viewer":false,"edge_follow":{"count":132},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"Keanu Reeves","has_ar_effects":false,"has_clips":false,"has_guides":false,"has_channel":false,"has_blocked_viewer":false,"highlight_reel_count":1,"has_requested_viewer":false,"id":"33898987401","is_business_account":true,"is_professional_account":true,"is_joined_recently":false,"business_category_name":null,"overall_category_name":null,"category_enum":"FAN_PAGE","category_name":"Fanpage","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"edge_mutual_followed_by":{"count":0,"edges":[]},"profile_pic_url":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/121112822_341270273848621_2563574417911225938_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=qf8TZWfw2-gAX_lKXUu&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=592de88f9e7925a92349d9d87383c93c&oe=609B402F&_nc_sid=7bff83","profile_pic_url_hd":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/121112822_341270273848621_2563574417911225938_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=qf8TZWfw2-gAX_lKXUu&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=26d0ea8aa7fb0637e0d868bc3e51b656&oe=609D5957&_nc_sid=7bff83","requested_by_viewer":false,"should_show_category":true,"username":"keanu_reeevesss","connected_fb_page":null,"edge_felix_video_timeline":{"count":1,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[{"node":{"__typename":"GraphVideo","id":"2375005703968353020","shortcode":"CD1txq8j2r8","dimensions":{"height":1918,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/117336467_864007477461758_5575865988045688474_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=2DiL3v9iuxsAX9krUWx&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=512f81cdd25dc2fbb62f7c12b51abace&oe=6079B2D7&_nc_sid=7bff83","edge_media_to_tagged_user":{"edges":[]},"fact_check_overall_rating":null,"fact_check_information":null,"gating_info":null,"sharing_friction_info":{"should_have_sharing_friction":false,"bloks_app_url":null},"media_overlay_info":null,"media_preview":"ABcqrTzJgkfxeg4BA5H9asWt4kcbDnc3IOB6Y55qlOhhYxcFQx7d8cnPXrx+dEcanhRk++O9YtdDXzKdwrhiWJbJ+8e/+fy9KKtXibSoXqRyP6+2fSirWwmLAvnzF5RwQTgnaCTnHPPTOfwoP+jNlvmHUEdx7fjVY3jbyeCPQjj8B/KnyTwugXbg9Se5PtjjH4UmnfXYd1YinmDnI5J70VX4oqyBUjMhwvXk0zpwavaf99v93+oqxdqMRHAyScnuee9TfWw7aXKKWsjjdjAPQk4z9O9FasvRaKnmZVj/2Q==","owner":{"id":"33898987401","username":"keanu_reeevesss"},"is_video":true,"accessibility_caption":null,"dash_info":{"is_dash_eligible":true,"video_dash_manifest":"<MPD xmlns=\"urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011\" minBufferTime=\"PT1.500S\" type=\"static\" mediaPresentationDuration=\"PT0H1M53.667S\" maxSegmentDuration=\"PT0H0M2.020S\" profiles=\"urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011,http://dashif.org/guidelines/dash264\">\n <Period duration=\"PT0H1M53.667S\">\n  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment=\"true\" maxWidth=\"1280\" maxHeight=\"720\" maxFrameRate=\"30\" par=\"16:9\" lang=\"und\" subsegmentAlignment=\"true\" subsegmentStartsWithSAP=\"1\">\n   <Representation id=\"17865146203989429vd\" mimeType=\"video/mp4\" codecs=\"avc1.4D401F\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" frameRate=\"30\" sar=\"1:1\" startWithSAP=\"1\" bandwidth=\"399597\" FBQualityClass=\"hd\" FBQualityLabel=\"1280w\" FBPlaybackResolutionMos=\"0:100.00,480:92.96,640:92.26,1280:92.94\">\n    <BaseURL>https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.16885-16/117756842_592878301590333_133402499755935140_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=109&amp;_nc_ohc=cHhzIcOj_5AAX_uIbvL&amp;edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&amp;ccb=7-4&amp;oh=3d6e7843ae2e3c2b0449ffd68ec6ca9e&amp;oe=607940A5&amp;_nc_sid=7bff83</BaseURL>\n    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact=\"true\" indexRange=\"909-1624\" FBFirstSegmentRange=\"1625-53919\" FBSecondSegmentRange=\"53920-145986\" FBPrefetchSegmentRange=\"1625-145986\">\n      <Initialization range=\"0-908\"/>\n    </SegmentBase>\n   </Representation>\n  <Representation id=\"17865146350989429v\" mimeType=\"video/mp4\" codecs=\"avc1.4D401F\" width=\"806\" height=\"454\" frameRate=\"30\" sar=\"1:1\" startWithSAP=\"1\" bandwidth=\"192636\" FBQualityClass=\"hd\" FBQualityLabel=\"806w\" FBPlaybackResolutionMos=\"0:100.00,480:88.74,640:87.94,1280:89.04\">\n    <BaseURL>https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.16885-16/117302370_619212445400389_4326250607583108995_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=101&amp;_nc_ohc=9EQROHS6qwEAX-Id9Pw&amp;tn=dMiLRuwWeMXAFeib&amp;edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&amp;ccb=7-4&amp;oh=9566187743247e297b7bfb7c58e83d2d&amp;oe=6079B0ED&amp;_nc_sid=7bff83</BaseURL>\n    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact=\"true\" indexRange=\"910-1625\" FBFirstSegmentRange=\"1626-23596\" FBSecondSegmentRange=\"23597-65008\" FBPrefetchSegmentRange=\"1626-65008\">\n      <Initialization range=\"0-909\"/>\n    </SegmentBase>\n   </Representation>\n  </AdaptationSet>\n <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment=\"true\" lang=\"und\" subsegmentAlignment=\"true\" subsegmentStartsWithSAP=\"1\">\n   <Representation id=\"17865146137989429ad\" mimeType=\"audio/mp4\" codecs=\"mp4a.40.2\" audioSamplingRate=\"44100\" startWithSAP=\"1\" bandwidth=\"130020\">\n    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri=\"urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011\" value=\"2\"/>\n    <BaseURL>https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.16885-16/117673694_297848871499653_2941826336409857302_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=109&amp;_nc_ohc=2eTCp04upn4AX-nd3e5&amp;edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&amp;ccb=7-4&amp;oh=0f582e6e06ecfa684071d463fc287ccb&amp;oe=60795C42&amp;_nc_sid=7bff83</BaseURL>\n    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact=\"true\" indexRange=\"866-1581\" FBFirstSegmentRange=\"1582-34520\" FBSecondSegmentRange=\"34521-66954\" FBPrefetchSegmentRange=\"1582-66954\">\n      <Initialization range=\"0-865\"/>\n    </SegmentBase>\n   </Representation>\n  </AdaptationSet>\n </Period>\n</MPD>","number_of_qualities":2},"has_audio":true,"tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJ1dWlkIjoiMDE2ZGE0MWI2NmVlNDVlZDhjODMyZjk0MGNiM2JjYWQyMzc1MDA1NzAzOTY4MzUzMDIwIiwic2VydmVyX3Rva2VuIjoiMTYxODQxNTc3NDE0OHwyMzc1MDA1NzAzOTY4MzUzMDIwfDE2NDQyMzcxMTB8NmQwMThiMDBkODk1ZjhhMGVhODc1ZDVhN2MwOWQ1YWY4ZGQ4NjFkZjkwMGUyMWRlM2FlNjExMDY5MDZkOThjOCJ9LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIifQ==","video_url":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.16885-16/117756842_592878301590333_133402499755935140_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjEyODAuaWd0di5kZWZhdWx0IiwicWVfZ3JvdXBzIjoiW1wiaWdfd2ViX2RlbGl2ZXJ5X3Z0c19vdGZcIl0ifQ&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=cHhzIcOj_5AAX_uIbvL&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&vs=17865146203989429_3621706050&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdLclRCQWM5czQ4OE9Cc0NBS1FGR3VMZDhOa0JidlZCQUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHTjZPQXdlRnR5NVk1QTRCQUJZdG1XeDNkOU1vYnZWQkFBQUYVAgLIAQAoABgAGwGIB3VzZV9vaWwBMRUAACbqqLbdrpC8PxUCKAJDMywXQFxqn752yLQYEmRhc2hfYmFzZWxpbmVfMV92MREAdewHAA%3D%3D&ccb=7-4&oe=607940A5&oh=613da159dda7b0ccec7e8acf238f8e7b&_nc_sid=7bff83","is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Photo by Keanu Reeves on April 03, 2021. May be an image of 1 person.","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"Happy Easter everyone \ud83d\udc23 \n_\n#keanu #keanureeves #keanureevesofficial #keanureevesedit #keanureevesmovies #keanureevesfans\n#recent #redbubble #keanureevesquotes #keanureevesmemes #keanureevesfan #johnwick \n#billandtedsexcellentadventure #billandted3 #billandtedfacethemusic #billandtedsbogusjourney #johnwick2 #johnwick3parabellum"}}]},"edge_media_to_comment":{"count":232},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1617518071,"edge_liked_by":{"count":7582},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":7582},"location":null,"thumbnail_src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/167552986_894782291370369_8557490528643166501_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=TtS48mcRpCcAX_NqW8-&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=1b7ede7860987e331cd74c10dae9128c&oe=609DAB05&_nc_sid=7bff83","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/167552986_894782291370369_8557490528643166501_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=TtS48mcRpCcAX_NqW8-&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=a137287e4b4c7f7f34e78fc3a11d66b9&oe=609CBB02&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/167552986_894782291370369_8557490528643166501_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=TtS48mcRpCcAX_NqW8-&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=a63d708a8bb135f2f8fd7796aca526a2&oe=609CCE88&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/167552986_894782291370369_8557490528643166501_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=TtS48mcRpCcAX_NqW8-&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=7cc8d66eed1bb9df5b4a222010ca8d4a&oe=609CF6FA&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/167552986_894782291370369_8557490528643166501_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=TtS48mcRpCcAX_NqW8-&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=ffd4e7fbec6fb59f9551de7e47fbd92a&oe=609BC6BF&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/167552986_894782291370369_8557490528643166501_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=TtS48mcRpCcAX_NqW8-&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=1b7ede7860987e331cd74c10dae9128c&oe=609DAB05&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":640,"config_height":640}]}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2543015183208317084","shortcode":"CNKmtXtjoCc","dimensions":{"height":1350,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/167786363_1047742872419077_6852157846565778114_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=Gh-fWMaXg7UAX9k5ruf&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=cac8d7852a188ed6fea32651d22110f4&oe=609CDD3C&_nc_sid=7bff83","edge_media_to_tagged_user":{"edges":[]},"fact_check_overall_rating":null,"fact_check_information":null,"gating_info":null, "thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/166078033_105796258192324_7469383668393212344_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=NF-6P8G2-P0AX_Bz9VR&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=df13b42cbd95fc3ea2fc31ea1a3b4cd2&oe=609DE836&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/166078033_105796258192324_7469383668393212344_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=NF-6P8G2-P0AX_Bz9VR&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=82eb513be5c06dc5137f07bf27fb4d29&oe=609DD274&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/166078033_105796258192324_7469383668393212344_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=NF-6P8G2-P0AX_Bz9VR&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=ba378fde415b52ceff75cbf2134a3e36&oe=609ABF8E&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/166078033_105796258192324_7469383668393212344_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=NF-6P8G2-P0AX_Bz9VR&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=555f77e01f003c8781c967664123de92&oe=609D994B&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/166078033_105796258192324_7469383668393212344_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=NF-6P8G2-P0AX_Bz9VR&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=119a7c56269c16adce7d7d1edaade373&oe=609E11B1&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":640,"config_height":640}]}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2538664668831762150","shortcode":"CM7JhDdjUbm","dimensions":{"height":1349,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/166307722_935658700596004_1185660057401132606_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=biHV07fVKpoAX8CTfUa&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=65df2f72f21eab2624566db21c19e865&oe=609CD2D4&_nc_sid=7bff83","edge_media_to_tagged_user":{"edges":[]},"fact_check_overall_rating":null,"fact_check_information":null,"gating_info":null,"sharing_friction_info":{"should_have_sharing_friction":false,"bloks_app_url":null},"media_overlay_info":null,"media_preview":"ACEqaVMG0j7oIPbqeetTLflnAwACQDn37/y6025kjwFPoDkfp/n2rP2EsB6sPyBz/SgDQvnmAZ1OFjIyvqCOevU5Pr06c1ETI3O0hWGRgE4OOpz3+lTyuwPyqXZu/A+n5f8A16o/aJS2S23HG0AY49z39T/hQA3f/nmil+3Sf3h/3yaKAHllkTDDoOo69OvsaLePG1xkg88+p/w/nUUYBH3mXd1UKMenXP8ATitl3WBAD2xwOtACZ4IHB/rVPyAGzjoSfrxgfz/KtItwfUVVaTHOT/wEYoAy/sE/90/lRV/cvq35/wD16KAILcB3XHTrntx6nsfY0+Vg7lh9PyqvppO9x22nipwKALYuA+UIwSp79fXH0qvEcDaTz796q3XAXH94VNN0zQBa2j0oqDcfU0UAf//Z","owner":{"id":"33898987401","username":"keanu_reeevesss"},"is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Photo by Keanu Reeves on March 27, 2021. May be a black-and-white image of 1 person, standing and outdoors.","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"Me when i slip in the shower, because I\u2019m to lazy to get a shower mat \ud83d\ude02\n_\n#keanu #keanureeves #keanureevesofficial #keanureevesedit #keanureevesmovies #keanureevesfans\n#recent #redbubble #keanureevesquotes #keanureevesmemes #keanureevesfan #johnwick \n#billandtedsexcellentadventure #billandted3 #billandtedfacethemusic #billandtedsbogusjourney #johnwick2 #johnwick3parabellum"}}]},"edge_media_to_comment":{"count":78},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1616852433,"edge_liked_by":{"count":4350},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":4350},"location":null,"thumbnail_src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.117.937.937a/s640x640/166307722_935658700596004_1185660057401132606_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=biHV07fVKpoAX8CTfUa&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=ab43c0e05e314af6eecab77e0c61c7d3&oe=609CD782&_nc_sid=7bff83","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.117.937.937a/s150x150/166307722_935658700596004_1185660057401132606_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=biHV07fVKpoAX8CTfUa&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=5162b23e764acc32d1d739468ac946ea&oe=609B51C7&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.117.937.937a/s240x240/166307722_935658700596004_1185660057401132606_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=biHV07fVKpoAX8CTfUa&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=8e469103781b7ddb116bb8153d303279&oe=609D8001&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.117.937.937a/s320x320/166307722_935658700596004_1185660057401132606_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=biHV07fVKpoAX8CTfUa&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=de630c63c461dcb1ad8a6a9e73d6b32d&oe=609E0DBF&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.117.937.937a/s480x480/166307722_935658700596004_1185660057401132606_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=biHV07fVKpoAX8CTfUa&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=f5011da1c5fa91c9627a3f668522e38b&oe=609D0DFA&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.117.937.937a/s640x640/166307722_935658700596004_1185660057401132606_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=biHV07fVKpoAX8CTfUa&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=ab43c0e05e314af6eecab77e0c61c7d3&oe=609CD782&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":640,"config_height":640}]}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2537079986021264550","shortcode":"CM1hM4ljOym","dimensions":{"height":1080,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/163295734_285926319598830_6423887269014041308_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=VT_sndGJjA0AX-jkiqY&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=d1b7cbb00cd3e03362e3fc26eda1a47d&oe=609DD0F7&_nc_sid=7bff83","edge_media_to_tagged_user":{"edges":[]},"fact_check_overall_rating":null,"fact_check_information":null,"gating_info":null,"sharing_friction_info":{"should_have_sharing_friction":false,"bloks_app_url":null},"media_overlay_info":null,"media_preview":"ACoqhOBzSH2qvKd8gj7VL91yq9D0A7Y4/WpGJ5bynahAwMkmodpBKt1HpVo/u+TjPpnke59qrogmJIOCDgAfzPt70wt95C1JSbuSp6ilqiDVgtFl/ePnAPAHfFFxGYw208YJz3PoD9P8KlspNylPTn86ZqG5Ys9icfrUlmMrlTuHX+f1qfz/AJflUA5HT+R9R/KqueKcrADmtGiUyVuSSe/Wo80vXk1CTzSsI3rGPguenT+tV9Rd2ABI2j9fwrO8xkc7SR9CRVcEk5PJpJDuPJoHJFKetIKsksE1WK1YNMpDP//Z","owner":{"id":"33898987401","username":"keanu_reeevesss"},"is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Photo by Keanu Reeves on March 25, 2021. May be an image of 3 people, people standing and indoor.","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"I think the worst Keanu movie is definitely Knock Knock! Who agrees? \n_\n#keanu #keanureeves #keanureevesofficial #keanureevesedit #keanureevesmovies #keanureevesfans\n#recent #redbubble #keanureevesquotes #keanureevesmemes #keanureevesfan #johnwick \n#billandtedsexcellentadventure #billandted3 #billandtedfacethemusic #billandtedsbogusjourney #johnwick2 #johnwick3parabellum"}}]},"edge_media_to_comment":{"count":439},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1616663524,"edge_liked_by":{"count":11779},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":11779},"location":null,"thumbnail_src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/163295734_285926319598830_6423887269014041308_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=VT_sndGJjA0AX-jkiqY&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=3add970a30fb05ed8b2b18ab28562bc5&oe=609B070D&_nc_sid=7bff83","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/163295734_285926319598830_6423887269014041308_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=VT_sndGJjA0AX-jkiqY&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=9c546c4bb8c796152a4dd7a20d2c17b5&oe=609B338A&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/163295734_285926319598830_6423887269014041308_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=VT_sndGJjA0AX-jkiqY&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=1cb7f47e70234c048c54cee517821b89&oe=609B4B10&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/163295734_285926319598830_6423887269014041308_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=VT_sndGJjA0AX-jkiqY&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=8588085aa7854f5e4e454b2eda164e41&oe=609B6C72&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/163295734_285926319598830_6423887269014041308_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=VT_sndGJjA0AX-jkiqY&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=67b9eae110b535f5b6a85dedc1718f3b&oe=609AC1F7&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/163295734_285926319598830_6423887269014041308_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=VT_sndGJjA0AX-jkiqY&edm=ABfd0MgAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=3add970a30fb05ed8b2b18ab28562bc5&oe=609B070D&_nc_sid=7bff83","config_width":640,"config_height":640}]}}]},"edge_saved_media":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_media_collections":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]}}},"toast_content_on_load":null,"show_view_shop":false,"profile_pic_edit_sync_props":null,"always_show_message_button_to_pro_account":false}
```